# Product $\left[\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right]^{1/2}\cdot\left[\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}4\right)\right]^{1/4}\ \cdots$

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-product, nested-radicals

I came across this question in the following form:

Compute the following infinite product

$$\left[\sin (x)\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]^{1/2}\cdot \left[\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right]^{1/4}\cdot \left[\sin \left(\frac{x}{4}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{8}\right)\right]^{1/8}  \cdots$$

And I have been unable to solve it or to find similar problems online, which might guide me to the solution.

However, I was able to convert it into a nested radical form, but after that I'm out of ideas. Could really use a bit of help. Thanks!

Here's the nested radical form I mentioned:

$$\sqrt{\sin (x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sqrt{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{4}\right) \sqrt {\sin \left(\frac{x}{4}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{8}\right) \ldots}}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula $2\sin x \cos x = \sin 2x$ recursively
$$
\lim _{N \to \infty} \prod _{n=0} ^{N} \frac{S^{2^{-n-1}}_{x 2^{-n}} C^{2^{-n-1}}_{x 2^{-n-1}} 2^{2^{-n-1}}  S^{2^{-n-1}}_{x 2^{-n-1}}  }{ 2^{2^{-n-1}} S^{2^{-n-1}}_{x 2^{-n-1}} } 
= \lim _{N \to \infty} \prod _{n=0} ^{N} \frac{S^{2^{-n}}_{x 2^{-n}} } {2^{2^{-n-1}} S^{2^{-n-1}}_{x 2^{-n-1}} }
$$
I believe you can start from here.

Comment: Thank you! I've arrived at the solution.

Comment: really cute approach (+1)!